# React - Invalid hook call when calling useTimer() inside useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having an issue trying to get accurate timing working in a React Native app. Below is a bare bones version of my problem.

I can get it working by using setTimeout however it's inaccurate, I am trying to use `useTimer` which is an accurate timer. However as I am creating the timer inside a useEffect and not in the component body im getting an `Invalid Hook Call, Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component`

Struggling to find a way around this issue.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { useTimer } from "react-use-precision-timer";

const stateTransistions = {
  in: 'out',
  out: 'in'
}

export const useBreath = () => {

  const [breathState, setBreathState] = React.useState(stateTransistions.in)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // below works but is inaccurate 
    // setTimeout(() => setBreathState(stateTransistions[breathState]), 1000)
    
    // Invalid hook call
    useTimer({
      startImmediately: true,
      runOnce: true,
      delay: 1000,
      callback: () => {
        setBreathState(stateTransistions[breathState])
      },
    });
  }, [breathState]);

  return {
    breathState,
  };
};

export default function TabOneScreen() {
  const { breathState } = useBreath()
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{breathState}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hooks must not be called into javascript function which are not a function component or a custom hook.

Note that hooks only works if each render of your component call the same number of hooks. Calling a hook based on a condition (inside `useEffect` handler with `[breathState]` argument) is illegal because each render will not call the same number of hooks.

I would use `useTimer` hook like this : (removing the `runOnce` parameter)

```
export const useBreath = () => {

  const [breathState, setBreathState] = React.useState(stateTransistions.in)

  useTimer({
    startImmediately: true,
    delay: 1000,
    callback: () => {
      setBreathState(stateTransistions[breathState]);
    }
  });

  return {
    breathState
  };
};
```

I added an example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bm5i2n?file=src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very much in the code. You can't use useTimer inside of a useEffect.

Take it outside of the `useEffect` and it should work fine.

```
export const useBreath = () => {
useTimer({
      startImmediately: true,
      runOnce: true,
      delay: 1000,
      callback: () => {
        setBreathState(stateTransistions[breathState])
      },
    });

...
}
```

Comment: Sorry this will not work, if I don't have it inside of useEffect there is nothing moving the breathState on to the next transisiton

Comment: Then you need to update the way you are doing that function. You can't use 2 hooks inside of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Move `useTimer` hook outside `useEffect` & invoke `timer.start()` inside `useEffect`.

```
export const useBreath = () => {

  const [breathState, setBreathState] = React.useState(stateTransistions.in)
  const timer = useTimer({ .... });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    timer.start();
  }, [breathState]);

  return {
    breathState,
  };
};
```

As in the [demo example](https://justinmahar.github.io/react-use-precision-timer/demo) in the project docs.